# Harman Kardon sb26 power cable

Tags: speakers, cable

I'm looking for a power cable bit I cant't find the reference of this cable.   The product is the sb26 Harman Kardon, the boomerspeaker

Comment: Looks like a standard figure-8 cable to me. Search for "figure 8 power cable", you'll get a ton of results.

Comment: Hi @ArtOfCode.  I believe since the site is in Beta, and its number of unanswered questions is its main weakness, it would help if you could expand your comment as an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Touché, @Alex. Feel free to take this one :)

Comment: What's ironic is, that I actually posted a link to this thread in the Meta question that I asked...

Answer (score 1):

The name of the cable required for the boomerspeaker is a Figure-8 cable.  However, in the future, when posting such a question, it would help if you could include the image of what it is that you need.  It took a bit of searching to find a picture with the image of the power nest.  Finally found it on NewEgg. [image: https://ssl-images.newegg.com/productimage/86-111-001-13.jpg].